# Disable Desktop Window Manager Session Manager

Tags: windows-7, services

I found that my desktop is very slow because Desktop Window Manager Session Manager consumes heavy memory.

I want to disable it but just worry any negative affect.

Windows 7 64 bit desktop, SP1 installed. 4G memory. DirectX 11

The graph card: AMD Radeon HD 7470. Driver: 8.922.0.0

Comment: Disabling the Desktop Windows Manager (DWM) is only going to cure the symptops (maybe), but not the actual cause. Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? Is SP1 installed? What are the technical specifications? What's your graphic card model? Which driver version are you currently using?

Comment: Yes, please see my update. Sometime Kaspersky consumes a lot, but I can't disable it. It is required by the company.

Comment: Being a company machine you should contact your IT department. Assuming there's a newer driver version available for your graphic card, installing it might fix or mitigate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it if you don't use Aero or need to alt-tab, but I think your better option is to determine WHY it is "consuming heavy memory".  But yes, you can disable it in `Services` if you so desire.